# Dynamic height resizing in React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to React Native, and I am trying to create a FlatList with list items that have dynamic heights. Basically, all list items are Texts with numberOfLines set to 1 and have a static height, but if the list item is selected, the text and height are allowed to expand. The selected item is tracked as a state variable. Currently, when a list item's height is expanded, no list item below it is re-rendered and they end up getting cut off, so how can I ensure that all items visible are still rendered?

Original:

[image: Original List]

After item selected:

[image: After item selected]

List item:

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={[
      styles.listItem,
      props.active ? styles.listItemActive : styles.listItemInactive,
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.listItemText} onPress={props.onPress}>
        <Text numberOfLines={props.active ? null : 1}>{props.title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={props.onDelete}>
        <Text>X</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listItem: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ccc",
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  listItemInactive: {
    height: 30,
  },
  listItemActive: {
    backgroundColor: "#95bdfc",
  },
  listItemText: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingVertical: 5,
  },
  closeButton: {
    width: "10%",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#8c8b8b",
  },
});
```

Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    data={goals}
    renderItem={(itemData) => (
      <GoalItem
        active={selectedGoal == itemData.item.id}
        onPress={changeSelectedItemHandler.bind(this, itemData.item.id)}
        onDelete={removeItemHandler.bind(this, itemData.item.id)}
        title={itemData.item.value}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some approach like:
getting the length of the text and according to that have the value for height ;i am gonna make it clear ;
i have two text in my datas;

> 1. 'Hello World From React Native'
> 2. 'Hello'

so if i want to give them diffrent height according to its length you can use short, inline if statement.

```
<View style={{height:props.text.length<10?20:30}}>
<Text> {props.text}</Text>
</View>
```

i hope it helps

Comment: Is there any way to avoid hardcoding the height, as I would prefer to make it automatically size self to contain the text

Comment: you can use flexShrink:1 and whatever your text is it will take its height and doesn't overflow